# Jboss as 7.1 admin console hangs on loading

Tags: java, jboss, java-7

I installed JBOSS AS 7.1 with JDK 1.7 and i create a management user , but when i ago to localhost:8080 > Console admin it's hang on loading, it doesn't show me a form to log in,

This is log when i started server :

```
7:54:53,084 INFOS [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
17:54:53,259 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
17:54:53,299 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting
17:54:54,099 INFO  [org.xnio] XNIO Version 3.0.3.GA
17:54:54,099 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
17:54:54,106 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.3.GA
17:54:54,113 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] JBoss Remoting version 3.2.3.GA
17:54:54,132 INFO  [org.jboss.as.logging] JBAS011502: Removing bootstrap log handlers
17:54:54,135 INFO  [org.jboss.as.configadmin] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26) JBAS016200: Activating ConfigAdmin Subsystem
17:54:54,152 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
17:54:54,164 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
17:54:54,181 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (JBoss IronJacamar 1.0.9.Final)
17:54:54,196 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) JBAS011940: Activating OSGi Subsystem
17:54:54,209 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) JBAS013101: Activating Security Subsystem
17:54:54,213 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS013100: Current PicketBox version=4.0.7.Final
17:54:54,223 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
17:54:54,246 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
17:54:54,338 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
17:54:54,341 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
17:54:54,400 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management.AbstractServerConfig] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.0.2.GA
17:54:54,779 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-3) Démarrage de Coyote HTTP/1.1 sur http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080
17:54:54,924 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS017100: Listening on localhost/127.0.0.1:9999
17:54:54,931 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory E:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments
17:54:54,931 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS017100: Listening on localhost/127.0.0.1:4447
17:54:55,083 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
17:54:55,155 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
17:54:55,156 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015874: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started in 2302ms - Started 133 of 208 services (74 services are passive or on-demand)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try with the respective port for the management console then. Your log states the following: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990.